# How can I batch/mass create users for a Filezilla FTP server?

Tags: user-accounts, script, batch-file, filezilla, ftp

I recently inherited two FTP servers; both systems run Filezilla Server. One has a small user-base so creating users is a small task. The other is huge and needs to have 300+ users created. I estimate that several hundred users may be added yearly so, manually creating accounts would be a bit of a pain.

Are there any options on scripting user account creation?

Comment: So, presumably you'll have a list of the user accounts to be created in some easily parsed format, like CSV, or something?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Filezilla project have an [example script](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Transfer_user_accounts_from_Another_FTP_Server)